# Knockout select binding, not remembering value when options added late

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout to create a select element, the options have to be set late (the options are set by loaded them from a server). This is causing the initial value to be lost. Below I have some working code it does what I want, but with the loading from server replaced with a static table.

If the line `setupSelect();` is moved to the end of the script (this simulates the asynchronous ajax call to the server), then the select asks me to choose.

I think that when there are no choices the value is overwritten, then the choices arrive, but the value is now null.

It looks like I know what the problem is, but don't know how to get it to work.

Can you tell me how to get it to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>
      Your thing:
      <select data-bind="options:      (function(){return $root.select1.rows;})(), 
                         optionsText:  function(item){return item.name;},
                         optionsValue: function(item){return item.id;},
                         value: selectedThing1, 
                         optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
      </select>

      <span data-bind="visible: selectedThing1">
        You have chosen a thing with id
        <span data-bind="text: selectedThing1() ? 
                         selectedThing1() : 
                         'unknown'">
        </span>.
      </span>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
      var viewModel = {
          select: {rows: ko.observableArray() },
          selectedThing : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
      };

      function setupSelect(){
      //in the real application rows_raw is populated from a server using $.ajax
          var rows_raw= [
              {name: "a thing",        id:1},
              {name: "one more thing", id:2},
              {name: "another thing",  id:3}
          ];

          $.each(rows_raw, function(index, item){
              viewModel.select.rows.push(item);
          });
      }

      //setupSelect(); //when loading from server (using $.ajax in async mode), then this line is effectivly moved to the end of the script.

      viewModel.selectedThing(2); //set ititial value
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

      setupSelect(); //when loading from server (using $.ajax in async mode), then this line is effectivly moved to the end of the script.
    </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

You can also see both examples here http://jsfiddle.net/V33NT/1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is default bahavior: Knockout forces the value to match an existing option, if there is no existings option it unsets the observable.

However there is new setting in KO 3.1. which is called `valueAllowUnset` and it is addressing exactly this scenario.

From [Knockout.js 3.1 Released](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/03/knockout-3-1-released.html)

> - With this option set to true, Knockout does not force the value to match an existing option.
> - The selection will be set to an empty option in the case of a mismatch, but the value is not overwritten.
> - This is very useful in scenarios where options are lazily loaded and there is an existing value.

So if you upgrade to Knockout.js 3.1 you can write

```
<select data-bind="options:      (function(){return $root.select2.rows;})(), 
                   optionsText:  function(item){return item.name;},
                   optionsValue: function(item){return item.id;},
                   value: selectedThing2, 
                   valueAllowUnset: true, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
```

Demo [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amW4v/).

Comment: Well done, and well done to the knockout people, who fixed my problem, some time between me reading the manual yesterday and now.